# raspberry pi cameraついていくつか質問させてください。

Tags: raspberry-pi

raspberry piでカメラから取得した映像をwebページで見るっていうのをサンプルを見て試しているのですが、動画を載せているraspiのホームページにアクセスすると動画の枠は出ているのすが、肝心の中身が見れません。
動画のエンコードとかをやっているファイルがvideo.shという名前で中身が、

```
#!/bin/bash

base="/data/live"

cd $base

raspivid -n -w 720 -h 405 -fps 25 -vf -t 86400000 -b 1800000 -ih -o - \
| ffmpeg -y \
    -i - \
    -c:v copy \
    -map 0:0 \
    -f ssegment \
    -segment_time 4 \
    -segment_format mpegts \
    -segment_list "$base/stream.m3u8" \
    -segment_list_size 720 \
    -segment_list_flags live \
    -segment_list_type m3u8 \
    "segments/%08d.ts"

trap "rm stream.m3u8 segments/*.ts" EXIT

# vim:ts=2:sw=2:sts=2:et:ft=sh
```

取得した動画？を表示するhtmlの中身が

```
<video controls="controls" width="1280" height="720" autoplay="autoplay" >
  <source src="stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
```

こうなっています(これらはbody部内あって書く場所が違うとかはありません)。しかし動画が見れなくて何が原因なのかが分からないです。
またvideoタグの属性でcontrolsやautoplayは入れるとき="~~"は入れなかったと思うのですがこれではなんでそうなっているのでしょうか？

どなたか教えて欲しいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まずは、何が悪いか切り分けをしてはいかがでしょう？どこまで思惑通りに行ってますか？そのshを単独で動かして所望のファイルは生成されましたか？

Comment: shを単独で動かしてみたら生成したいファイルがでてなく、エラーが出ていました。問題を切り分けてもう少し考えてみます。
ありがとうございました。